# Add Aspects to ASP.NET MVC controller using AspectMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

We're looking at using an AOP framework for handling things like logging, tracing, and exception handling. I've built a prototype using PostSharp and now I'm trying to build the same functionality using AspectMap.

In a nutshell, I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application and I want an aspect that I can easily attach to my controller methods that shows the entry, exit, execution time, and argument values. My PoC is the basic MVC 3 Internet Application template (File > New > Project > Web > ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application > Internet). What I've done so far...

Created an AspectsRegistry

```
public class PoCRegistry : AspectsRegistry
{
    public PoCRegistry()
    {
        ForAspect<ProfileAttribute>().HandleWith<ProfileHandler>();
    }
}
```

Created a StructureMapControllerFactory

```
public class StuctureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance( RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType )
    {
        if( controllerType == null ) return null;

        try
        {
            return ObjectFactory.GetInstance( controllerType ) as Controller;
        }
        catch( StructureMapException )
        {
            Debug.WriteLine( ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave() );
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Registered everything in Application_Start

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters( GlobalFilters.Filters );
    RegisterRoutes( RouteTable.Routes );

    ObjectFactory.Initialize( ie => ie.AddRegistry( new PoCRegistry() ) );
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory( new StuctureMapControllerFactory() );
}
```

At this point the application works, and I can see it's using my StructureMapControllerFactory to build the controller (debugger steps into that code). The problem is that I can't figure out where or how to "enrich" the controller that is generated. In the [tutorial](http://www.chrissurfleet.co.uk/post/2012/05/29/AspectMap-%E2%80%93-Aspect-Oriented-Programming-for-Complete-Beginners.aspx) it says I need to use something like the following:

```
For<ICaseController>()
    .Use<CaseController>()
    .EnrichWith( AddAspectsTo<CaseController> );
```

But in the tutorial that goes in the AspectRegistry, which doesn't seem like the right place in this situation because the registry isn't responsible for resolving the controller request, the controller factory is. Unfortunately the GetInstance() method in the controller factory returns an `object` and the EnrichWith() method needs a `SmartInstance`.

At this point I'm stuck. Any hints, pointers, or assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks correct according to the tutorial, even though if you're planning on just intercepting controller actions it seems a bit much work to do compared with ActionFilters. What is it you're having problems with?

Comment: I'm doing this as a prototype. Eventually we would be putting aspects on controller actions, business component methods, webform code-behind, etc, etc, etc. If I used ActionFilters I would have to write the code twice. What I'm having a problem with, as mentioned towards the end of the post, is that I can't figure out where to put the For<>.Use<>.EnrichWith() call.

Comment: The EnrichWith call should go in the AspectRegistry as the tutorial states. That will make the AddAspects create a Decorator/Wrapper for the CaseController and enable AspectMap to intercept the calls to the methods having handler attributes. The StructureMapControllerFactory delegates the responsibilty to construct controllers to the Container.

Comment: Upon a second look, I see your problem. The `StuctureMapControllerFactory` is going to get a request for the conrete type `CaseController`, but the proxying applied by AspectMap requires an interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is a use case I hadn't thought about to be honest. I'll setup a test project today and see what I can come up with. Bear with me!

**Update**

I've been playing around with the backend code (you can get a complete copy of the code from http://aspectmap.codeplex.com) and the relevant part is this:

```
public T AddAspectsTo<T>(T concreteObject)
    {
        ProxyGenerator dynamicProxy = new ProxyGenerator();

        return (T)dynamicProxy.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTargetInterface(typeof(T), concreteObject,
            new[] { (IInterceptor)new AspectInterceptor(attributeMap) });
    }
```

This is using the castle dynamic proxy stuff. Unfortunately the CreateInterfaceProxy... methods require that an interface is passed in (rather than a base class like I'd hoped). Now I've found this question:
[C# Dynamic Proxy 2 generate proxy from class with code in constructor ? How to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729166/c-sharp-dynamic-proxy-2-generate-proxy-from-class-with-code-in-constructor-how)

That seems to show that it could be possible to use CreateClassProxy. I've not had chance to try this out yet and I'm going away for a week away from the computer. If you want to try and wire it up though you're welcome to get the source from codeplex and give it a try though. If not I'll put something together when I return.

Answer (score -1):

Action filters can be used to provide such AOP functionality.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056%28v=vs.90%29.aspx